# how to run python code from javascript or html?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I wrote the code in python which reads the CSV file. Now, I want to run that python code from the javascript or HTML

Here is the python code

```
    with open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Summer.csv') as csvDataFile:
     csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
     for row in csvReader:
        print(row)
```

Here is the html and javascript code

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "C:\\Users\\Pictures\\test.py",
        success: function(response) {
            // here you do whatever you want with the response variable
        }
        });

    }
```

Comment: You will have to send a http request and the handler in the backend must be the one to invoke the script.

Comment: Client side JS can't run files. It can render other JS, or do something with HTML, but it can't run other language file

Comment: does PHP run the python file? FZs

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Summer.csv') as csvDataFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
         for row in csvReader:
           print(row)
```

bind this code in a function in py file

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "..\test.py\somefunctionName",
        success: function(response) {
            // here you do whatever you want with the response variable
        }
        });

    }
```

Use url paramater to invoke that function and you are good to go

Comment: Here I put the python code in the function.
  

    import csv
        
        def SomeFunctionName():
            with open('C:\\Users\\tmaga\\Desktop\\Summer.csv') as csvDataFile:
                csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
                for row in csvReader:
                   print(row)
        
        
        SomeFunctionName()

Comment: What do you want me to do in URL line code of javascript?

Comment: in url side invoke that function using the way how your url works like
./test/SomeFunctionName
this entirely depends upon how your urls are working for application.

Comment: Try to invoke this function directly from browser address bar whatever url it is it will work Can you understand what I mean?

Comment: I know what you mean but I don't know how to do that since I am kind of new in javascript.

Comment: Do you want me to use "get and post" with the request of http ?

Comment: If I ask you question do you have home page if yes what is the url of that page
somelike ___/index.
or if you have about page what is the url 
localhost:_____/about
To invoke a function try tying like this
localhost:______/test/SomeFunctionName
where test is your page name and SomeFunctionName is name of function where you added the python code.

Comment: anything is fine either get or post but first is to invoke the function via url than move on to invoking is via javascript ajax request.
1st task
Call the function directly from browser url can you do it?

Comment: You need to get that first some how before you can use it on javascript by the way what is your setup?

Comment: I called the function using ajax in javascript and jquery but somehow it doesn't work

Comment: type a print statement inside the function and see if you can actually call the function.

If your call is success then you need to return the Json object only